# Cancel Alarm in AlarmManager onReceive

Tags: android, alarmmanager

in Main activity Alarm start
Here's the code
         private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
         private AlarmManager manager;

```
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

    manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int interval = 10000; // 10 seconds

    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And How to cancel alarm in AlarmReceiver.class

```
   public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

static DatabaseHandler dbHandler;

private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private AlarmManager manager;

     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             // SHOW NOTIFICATION
         Log.e("DAYDAY", "" + "pasok");
         int days = 1;
         Toast.makeText(context, "DAYDAY", 10).show();
            if (days == 5) {
                dbHandler.deleteUser();

                    manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
                     Toast.makeText(context, "Canceled", 10).show();

            }else{
                int = days + 1;
                 dbHandler.update_days(i, emp_id, birthday);
            }


     }
```

}

if days equal to 5 then i will cancel the alarm.
but the error is the manager is null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you use the **manager**, you need to manually call:

```
manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get it again by using

**manager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);**

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null pointer because `pendingIntent`and `'alarm manager'`are not initialized any where in your code.

To cancel alarm try following code-

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
// get pending intent by unique tag value assigned previously
int tag = 0;
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, tag, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```